# Getting Started with Programming Microsoft CRM 4

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have gone through all the msdn stuff for getting started with the SDK for Microsoft CRM 4.

I am trying to find any other basic examples / blog posts about implementing the SDK for MS CRM4. Does anyone know of some blogs that cover this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do well to check out the Microsoft CRM SDK over at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928215.aspx).  You could also browse the [google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.crm.developer/), or check out [sites](http://stunnware.com/crm2) to [well known](http://mscrm4ever.blogspot.com/) CRM [MVPs](http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.com/).

Best advice, however, is to just start fooling around with it.  It's very intuitive once you understand the process of getting things done.

Answer (score 1):

I was in your shoes a while back, and I started by thinking of a "mini project" and doing it.  It will force you to find out more about CRM and you'll gain "practical experience".

How about getting a book - Working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 and working through some exercises there?

Comment: I agree with that book, it is a really good book.  The thing about CRM is you touch so many points in the infrastructure, active directory, exchange, iis, outlook and the list goes on, to know them all is very difficult.  So get some people that is good in each of the important areas in CRM